# how to do list_agg with a character limit of 1440 characters in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table as below, I have 1775 ids and length of id column is 10 characters, I want to create multiple groups of list_agg of ids with a limit of not more than 1440 characters to distribute 1775 ids into groups

| id | distributor_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | Sample_name1 |
| 2345678901 | Sample_name1 |
| 3456789012 | Sample_name1 |
| 4567890123 | Sample_name2 |
| 5678901234 | Sample_name2 |
| 6789012345 | Sample_name3 |
| 7890123456 | Sample_name3 |
| 8901234567 | Sample_name3 |

Required output is:

| group | id_count | list_agg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 1234567890,2345678901,3456789012... |
| 2 | 122 | 7890123456,5678901234,8901234567... |

Very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your ID space is symmetrically distributed you can use [WIDTH_BUCKET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/width_bucket.html)

```
with data1 as (
select 
    row_number() over (order by true)-1 as rn
from table(generator(rowcount=>100))
)
select 
    width_bucket(rn, 0, 100, 5) as group_id,
    count(*) as c,
    array_agg(rn) within group(order by rn) as bucket_values
from data1
group by 1
order by 1;
```

| GROUP_ID | C | BUCKET_VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ] |
| 2 | 20 | [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 ] |
| 3 | 20 | [ 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 ] |
| 4 | 20 | [ 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79 ] |
| 5 | 20 | [ 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 ] |

If your data is not symmetrical, you can allocate row numbers to each row, and then shave the yack again.

you can also be data driven:

```
    width_bucket(rn, (select min(rn) from data1), (select max(rn) from data1)+1, 5) as group_id,
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier done with `array_agg` but if you must use `listagg`, here is a spin on Simeon's answer. The basic idea is to keep track of length of numbers when stitched together and also account for the number of commas so we don't go over 1440 char limit.

```
create or replace temporary table t as

select row_number() over (order by true)-1 as id,
       uniform(1000000000, 1999999999, random()) as num
from table(generator(rowcount=>1775));

with cte as

(select *, ceil((sum(len(num)) over (order by id) + count(num) over (order by id) -1)/1440) as group_id
 from t)

select group_id, 
       count(num) as id_count, 
       listagg(num,',') as id_list, 
       len(id_list) as len_check
from cte
group by group_id
order by group_id;
```